# Как модифицировать npm пакет?

Tags: node.js, npm

У меня есть [пакет "node-images"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images) и мне нужно добавить в него функцию, рисующую пиксель чёрного цвета по заданным координатам. Я вручную скачал этот пакет с GitHub и изменил следующие файлы:
index.js - добавил строки

```
71. drawDot: function(x, y) {
72.     this._handle.dot(x, y);
72. },
```

src/Image.h - Добавил строки

```
207. 
208. static void DrawDot(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args);
```

src/Image.cc - Добавил строки

```
106. NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(tpl, "dot", DrawDot);
...
422.
423. void Image::DrawDot(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) { // {{{
424. 
425.     Image *dst;
426.     uint32_t x, y;
427.     Pixel *cp;
428. 
429.     dst = node::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Image>(args.This());
430. 
431.     x = args[0]->Uint32Value();
432.     y = args[1]->Uint32Value();
433.     
434.     cp = &color;
435.     cp->R = 0;
436.     cp->G = 0;
437.     cp->B = 0;
438.     cp->A = 0xFF;
439. 
440.     dst->pixels->data[x][y] = cp;
441. 
442.     args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::Undefined(args.GetIsolate()));
443. } // }}}
```

После этого ввёл npm i находясь в директории с пакетом и попытался выполнить следующий код

```
const images = require("images");
images(300, 300).drawDot(10,10);
```

Но получил ошибку:

> TypeError: this._handle.dot is not a function

Вопрос: Что я сделал не так и как мне добавить эту функцию?

Может быть полезно:
1. После установки пакета появляется файл /vendor/.../binding.node. Если открыть его как бинарный файл, то по адресу 0006d390 можно найти перечисление имён функций, но функции dot среди них нет.
2. Если вписать имя функции вручную, пакет будет крашиться при запуске, не выдавая ошибки.
3. Если изменить имя какой-либо функции в аргументах `NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD` (src/Image.cc), то при попытке вызова этой функции будет возникать ошибка, т.е. редактирование src/Image.cc влияет на пакет.

Comment: У вас, похоже, совсем нет понимания как работает система модулей в node.js. Начните изучение с руководства по ноде https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/428576/.

Comment: Нет, я хорошо с ней знаком. Проблема не в Node.js, а в исходниках на C++ - добавление новых функций ни к чему не ведёт, а удаление старых вызывает ошибку

Comment: Вы пытаетесь скачать чужой пакет и добавить в него свой код. Вам нужно добавлять изменения в ваш модуль и опубликовать его перед использованием.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы, добавляю я код в скаченный пакет или форк на ГитХабе. Результат один и тот же, проблема в части C++, а не Ноды

Comment: Ваш вопрос и его решение имеют очень косвенное отношение к `node.js` и `npm`. Замените эти теги на `c++`.

Comment: Я поставил тег c++ в первую очередь, но другие участники решили что он не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Проблема была в том, что бинарник при установке не компилировался, а скачивался готовый. Скомпилировал вручную - всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Более хорошей практикой в данном случае было б создание новой ф-ции в модуле **своего** проекта, типа "util.js" или "image_util.js" и последующего биндинга их к **своим** C++ исходникам.

Подход изменения чужого модуля чреват тем, что вам придется каждый раз это реализовывать после установки/обновления пакетов.